# Class cast exception when inflating a custom Relative Layout?

Tags: android

I get this exception when I try to inflate

07-22 19:15:39.903: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3810): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout

I have a base class:

```
public class UIBase extends RelativeLayout {}
```

And a more specific class:

```
public class Countdown extends UIBase {}
```

Then I try to inflate and it exceptions:

```
UIBase newView = (UIBase) inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, true);
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.Countdown xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/countdown"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countdownText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="0" />
</com.Countdown>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: Without seeing the layout file, and perhaps more of the code, it is difficult to advise you. Make sure your layout file has a `UIBase` or `Countdown` widget, not a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the documentation, inflate() returns "the root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file."

Since you passed in true, the return value is "parent", which is apparently not derived from UIBase.

Comment: This was it. I had to pass false though, not simply leave out the true. Good catch, thanks.